# mixture of string and number in macro

Tags: c, string, macros, numbers

I want to use this macro to put (if 'i' is greater than zero) the symbol '^' and the number I pass (i) to the macro

```
#define ESP(i) ((i>0) ? ("^"(i)) : "")
```

I want to call it in this way

```
printf("%+d%s", n1, ESP(i));
```

where 'i' is the index of a cycle, but the compilation reports me errors;
how can I modify the code to be right?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat dirty but should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DYNFORMAT(n, i) (i>0) ?"%+d%s%d\n" :"%+d%s%s\n", n, (i>0) ?"^" :"", (i>0) ?i :""

int main(void) 
{
  int i = 0;
  printf(DYNFORMAT(42, i));
  i = 1;
  printf(DYNFORMAT(42, i));
}
```

This should print:

```
+42
+42^1
```

Disclaimer: I am not sure whether this conforms to the Standard and how to get rid of the warning(s) it gives during compilation.

---

The clean approach would be to use two calls to `printf()`.

This can be implemented as a macro or a function.

As I love the pre-processor, the macro version here:

```
#define PRINT_ESP(n, i) \
do { \
  if (i = 0) \
    printf("%+d", n); \
  else \
    printf("%+d^%d", n, i); \
} while (0);
```

Comment: Note that `(i)` is not equivalent to `(i > 0)` if `i` is of a signed type.

Comment: Ahok, sure. But this a detail. Will correct this however. @JohnBollinger

Comment: I imagine your warning arises from this expression: `(i>0) ?i :""`.  You can avoid the warning and change that expression to plain `i` if you remove the trailing `%s` field descriptor from the second format string.

Answer (score 1):

Macros operate at compile time, not at run time.  They can perform a variety of text-mangling tricks, but they do not *evaluate* anything.  (They can certainly, however, expand to *code* that evaluates something.)  Putting the formatted value of variable `i` into a string involves evaluating `i`; no macro can do this.

You could instead expand the scope of the macro to include the whole `printf()` call:

```
#define PRINT_ESP(n1, i) do { \
    printf(((i > 0) ? "%+d^%d" : "%+d"), n1, i); \
} while (0)
```

Alternatively, you could use a macro to express just the format selection incorporated into the above macro definition, or you could just put the full `printf()` call above directly into your code.

All of these variations are based on the fact that arguments in excess of those required by the given format are evaluated prior to the call, but ignored by `printf()` itself.

Comment: This won't work, at least because the `%s` expects a "string" which isn't around in the argument list.

Comment: Much more straight forward, then my answer. Also cleaner, as it generates few warnings.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the (i) after the "^". Change your macro to this and it should work `#define ESP(i) ((i>0) ? ("^") : (""))`. Then in your printf statement if you want to print the value of i after the "^" then have something like this `printf("%s%d", ESP(i), i);` As far as I know I don't think you can format a string to include an integer inside a macro since that would require calling other functions, so you have to bring the i into the string inside your printf.

Comment: "*You don't need the (i) ...*" as far as I understand the question the (value of) `i` is an explicit must.

Comment: Well no, he wants the value of `i` to appear in the macro expansion.

Comment: Ooo, my bad from his explanation I thought he just wanted the  "^" printed, ok lemme remove this answer then

Comment: I think he has to move printing the i to the printf since leaving it in the macro would be a compile error, so I edited the answer. Sorry for the confusion